# How To Select Evaluated Value Of Expression<Func<T>> In Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, expression

I'm creating a system to generate variable search queries in EF.  To accomplish this I dynamically build up an `Expression<Func<T>>` like so.

```
Expression<Func<Entity, float>> matchScore = x => 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameLTB.Value))
{
    var words = NameLTB.Value.Split(' ').ToArray();
    var perWordValue = 2f / words.Length;
    foreach (var word in words)
        matchScore = ExpressionExt.Compose(matchScore, x => x.Name.Contains(word) ? perWordValue : 0f, Expression.Add);
}
//...
```

Then I order my query on this EF-compatible `Expression<T>` like so.

```
List<Entity> result;
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    result = context.Table.OrderByDescending(matchScore).Take(MaxResults).ToList();
```

The problem here is I don't know what the score was that caused the order to be the way it is.  I'd love to be able to do this.

```
List<Entity> result;
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    result = 
        (
            from x in context.Table
            let y = matchScore
            orderby y descending
            select new { Entity = x, MatchScore = y }
        )
        .ToList();
```

Of course the issue here is `y is Expression<T>` which isn't valid.  I could use `.Select(matchScore)` but then  don't have the original entity to go with it.

Comment: As I see `matchScore` initialize at once and doesn't change until you retrieve data from db. So you can compile `matchScore` and apply returned function to retrieved data from db that were downloaded in the memory. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine expressions with [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) like this:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, float>> matchScore = x => 0;
Expression<Func<Entity, float>> matchScoreInc;
string s = "a b";
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
{
    var words = s.Split(' ').ToArray();
    var perWordValue = 2f / words.Length;
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        matchScoreInc = x => matchScore.Invoke(x) + (x.Name.Contains(word) ? perWordValue : 0f);
        matchScore = matchScoreInc.Expand();
    }
}

var q =
    from x in table.AsExpandable()
    let y = matchScore.Invoke(x)
    orderby y descending
    select new { Entity = x, MatchScore = y };
```

Note the use of `Invoke`, `Expand` and `AsExpandable`.
Demo:

[image: demo]